# metadata.SetQuery don't work in Windows 8 but work in Windows 7

Tags: c#, metadata, jpeg

I try to save keywords to jpeg

```
metadata.SetQuery(@"/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/keywords", new string[] { "Hello", "Hello1" });
```

in Windows 7 all work perfectly but in Windows 8 don't work
What's problem?

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: no errors, just don't save